# what's this weird : JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Tunnel"

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

i was trying to fetch some data from the server to display in the react native app. it was worked before but i don't know what happened after, i added a console.log in the catch of fetch.. it showing me error like

> JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Tunnel"
>   - node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
>   - node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in 
>   - ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals

```
fetch(`${this.props.baseUrl}/products?page=${this.state.page}&per_page=10`,{
    method:"get",
    headers:{
        AUTH_TOKEN: this.props.AUTH_TOKEN
    }
}).then(res=>res.json()).then(data=>{
    if(data.success==true){
        this.page++;
        this.props.toggleLoading();
        this.props.loadProducts(data.products);
    }
}).catch(err=>console.log(err)); //error here ..i dont know why that's throwing this kinda error
```

Comment: Well the JSON text itself would be the place to look for the error.

Comment: The browser "Network" developer view will show you the actual response content.

Comment: I consistently inconsistently get this error.  It shows up for a few hours then goes away randomly.  It happens daily though and it frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because of ngrok stopped its tunnel, so your api returning some text/html instead json data,

Answer (score 0):

For me it was forgetting to update the ngrok url I had specified in a variable. Updating it fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

This can also be the result of starting to use a VPN:

- disconnect from the VPN
- restart ngrok
- use new ngrok url

Answer (score -1):

Hi are you using dotenv for your env variables? If you are, I also had the same error and i found out it was because my env variables were not updating which caused the tunnel url to not be found. You can try running ur app using this command: `expo r -c` or refer to the solutions in this link https://github.com/zetachang/react-native-dotenv/issues/24